# how can I perform both negative lookahead and negative lookbehind in a single perl regx?

Tags: perl, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

In a multiline string, in each line, I want to delete everything from the first unescaped percent sign to the end of the line; **with one exception**. If the unescaped percent sign occurs in the following position: `\d\d:\d\d%:\d\d`, then I want to leave it alone.

(The string is LaTeX / TeX code and the percent sign denotes a comment. I want to treat a comment inside an HH:MM:SS string as a special case, where seconds were commented out of a time string.)

The code below manages almost to do it:

1. it uses one negative lookbehind to leave `\%` alone
2. it uses "ungreedy" to match the first, not last, `%`
3. it uses another negative lookbehind to skip `\d\d:\d\d%`
4. BUT it fails to differentiate between `\d\d:\d\d%anything` and `\d\d:\d\d%\d\d`, skipping both.
5. My attempts at adding negative lookahead do not help. Is there a way to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $string = 'for 10\% and %delete-me
for 10\% and 2021-03-09 Tue 02:59%:02 NO DELETE %delete-me
for 10\% and 2021-03-09 Tue 04:09%anything  %delete-me
for 10 percent%delete-me';

print "original string:\n";
print "$string<<\n";

{
    my $tochange = $string;
    $tochange =~ s/
        (^.*?
        (?<!\\)
        )
        (\%.*)
        $/${1}/mgx;
    print "\ndelete after any unescaped %\n";
    print "$tochange<<\n";
}

{
    my $tochange = $string;
    $tochange =~ s/
        (^.*?
        (?<!\d\d:\d\d)
        (?<!\\)
        )
        (\%.*)
        $/${1}/mgx;
    print "\nexception for preceding HH:MM\n";
    print "$tochange<<\n";
}

{
    my $tochange = $string;
    $tochange =~ s/
        (^.*?
        (?<!\d\d:\d\d)
        (?<!\\)
        )
        (!?:\d\d)
        (\%.*)
        $/${1}/mgx;
    print "\nattempt to add negative lookahead\n";
    print "$tochange<<\n";
}


{
    my $tochange = $string;
    # attempt to add negative lookahead
    $tochange =~ s/
        (^.*?
        (?<!\d\d:\d\d)
        (?<!\\)
        )
        (\%.*)
        (!?:\d\d)
        $/${1}/mgx;
    print "\nattempt to add negative lookahead\n";
    print "$tochange<<\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might make use of [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) approach:

```
\d\d:\d\d%:\d\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<!\\)%.*
```

- `\d\d:\d\d%:\d\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` Match the pattern that you want to avoid
- `(?<!\\)%.*` Negative lookbehind, assert not `\` directly to the left and match `%` followed by the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d4rgcl/1) | [Perl demo](https://tio.run/##jZDNa4NAEMXv/hXT0CUqWDe2OfhRSqEWQkNbaI57WXRiBDPKulKE0n/dribp56WXx/Aew/zeNKiq5TB0LUKrVZnpGMb5VSoqqWhjy9r3cD5GVMA1zLe1ggUXDCTlwHKsUKO3R@uHH/Bg4fFLj4ew6RB4EC1DFvEAHp/gLl2nm/Tfq1cRD5mkXu9GgL9r0KDKkPRXMDfMjcHVMKtVWZQkKzjwR4IEzeJTemyVJJM59dR1tpNUoGl6TGPrm/kOrS9ykUejsElt9@Vh9ezY7v3tau282TfJmRAOu3B9v/i8JOhAB3KrUZmePXSEbSYbNE/8RXU6Z6xh@AA)

For example

```
$tochange =~ s/\d\d:\d\d%:\d\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<!\\)%.*//g;
```